# How to delete a row from Parent table without delete a row from Child table

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a row from Parent table without deleting or modifying row in the child table. For this what type referential integrity constraints of mysql i have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain the reason why you would need such a scenario?

I would consider flagging the parent row as deleted as opposed to "deleting" them permanently.

Comment: i'm having parent table. In the child table i'm tracking what are all changes done to the parent table. Atlast if row from the parent table deleted i wanna to keep track that this row got deleted by using child table

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are tracking in "child" is actually activity tracking / log of parent table changes. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

*Updated: sorry, I was wrong...*

Don't set referential integrity at all.

`Cascade` will delete children when deleting parent. `Restrict` will throw mySQL error. `Set Null` will set foreign key value in child table/tables to `NULL`. `No Action` according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) will be equivalent to `Restrict`.

Comment: In mysql tutorial No action is defined as follows. NO ACTION: In standard SQL, NO ACTION means no action in the sense that an attempt to delete or update a primary key value is not permitted to proceed if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.